# renderInContext taxes App Memory

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, uiimageview, uigraphicscontext

I'm running this code on a 2448 X 2448 pixel Image. `fullScaleView` is also 2448 X 2448 (`fullScreenView Rect:{{0, 0}, {2448, 2448}}`). The App memory jumps from 49.7MB to 240MB down to 172MB after the method is complete. It stays at 172MB. It doesn't seem like the app should still be running at such high a memory footprint after this one `renderInContext`. Where and how should I force a release? (iOS 7 XCode 5 ARC).

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fullScaleView.bounds.size, fullScaleView.opaque, 1.0);
[fullScaleView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Are you keeping a reference to `viewImage` outside the method?

Comment: Yes, I return viewImage directly after UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

Comment: That might be the large memory increase. It's going to be stored (I think) in an uncompressed bitmap. 2448x2448x32 is 192m.

Comment: why by 32? should it be by 4?

Comment: I was thinking of a 32-bit image, but like I say I don't really know the math of this. Either way, check whether the image is what's using that memory.

Comment: You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x 1024 in size. This is from Apple docs.

Comment: What format should it be in if I need it larger than 1024?

Answer (score 3):

The memory jumps because the image is huge - if you are sure that you won't need it anymore, you should wrap wherever you are using the returned image in an autorelease block:

e.g.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    UIImage *theReturnedImage = yourmethodthatreturnstherenderedimage();
    // do stuff with your image
}
```

Unfortunately, until you are finished using the image, it will take up space, so you just have to release it quickly.